# JQuery wont work externally

Tags: jquery

```
<head>
    <title> Slider </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/slider.js"></script>  
</head>

<div class="subTab">
     <ul>
         <li><a>First</a></li>
        <li><a>Second</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    // works here
    $(".subTab").css("left", 500);
    alert($(".subTab").position().left);
</script>
```

Content `js/javascript.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".subTab").css("left", 500);
    alert($(".subTab").position().left);    
});
```

Problem:

changing and outputting the `.position().left` of `.subTab` works locally in the `<script>` tags, but not externally in `js/javascript.js`. Why?

css:

```
.subTab
{
    z-index:12;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    padding-right:10px;
    border:1px solid #8C90FF;
    border-top:0px;
}
```

inside slider, we have index.php and the folder called js.

Comment: Are you sure your external script is being loaded? Maybe the path is just wrong?

Comment: it runs the rest of the code thats in the document.ready callback function, so yes.

Comment: js/javascript.js is missing `);` at the end of bracket

Comment: You're not showing where jQuery is loaded.  Is the script tag for it before or after the one for your external script?

Comment: @NathanD lol sorry I forgot copy that as well into my post.

Comment: I had a typo in my document.load callback function.. lol thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be including your external file incorrectly.

Try loading it with two periods in the relative path.

```
<head>
   // wont work in js/javascript.js
   <script src="../js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also try putting an alert in your javascript.js file to see if its actually getting loaded.  Or you could use firebug to see if its loaded.

If you can post the directory structure of your project, I can give you a more concrete answer.

It also appears that your code is not properly formatted.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".subTab").css("left", 500);
    alert($(".subTab").position().left);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".subTab").css("margin-left", 500);
    alert($(".subTab").position().left);    
})​
```